# x86 assembly extreme novice inquiry: "invalid instruction operands"?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32

The code below is only a small fraction of the program I am currently attempting to write, but no other parts of the program are relevant, so I only pasted what was necessary. Anyway, what I am trying to do is move the value stored within inputLoopCounter into ecx in order to determine how many times a loop should execute. However, when I attempt to assemble this program, I get the error mentioned in the question title. Can anybody explain the reason for this?

```
.data
inputLoopCounter BYTE -1

.code
mov   ecx,inputLoopCounter
```

Comment: Not an x86 expert, but perhaps the issue is placing a "BYTE" into a register that expects a 32-bit value?  Perhaps just load `cl` instead.  Actually, may need to use brackets [] as you are loading from memory too.  I'll leave it to the real experts who will be here shortly :)

Comment: Or `movsx ecx, byte ptr [inputLoopCounter]` if you really want your variable to be a byte but still want to load it into a dword register.

Comment: @Michael If it isn't absolutely necessary for it to be a byte, is it possible for me to change BYTE to DWORD in order to make it work? EDIT: Thank you, Jose Manuel Abarca Rodriguez, you answered my question. That was an extremely amateur mistake.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez Sure, why not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution would be to replace `inputLoopCounter BYTE -1` by `inputLoopCounter DWORD -1`.

Answer (score 0):

In MASM, `foo BYTE -1` is treated as declaring a "variable" with a fixed size.  Using that symbol later implies an operand-size for instructions that access it.

So MASM is trying to save you from yourself, stopping you from doing a dword (4-byte) load from a 1-byte variable.  This happens even if you have multiple bytes, like `foo db "foobar"` and *want* to load multiple characters; that's when `mov eax, dword ptr [foo]` is useful.

The other major flavour of Intel-syntax assembly language (NASM), will happily assemble an instruction that loads 4B from `[inputLoopCounter]`, regardless of what `inputLoopCounter` is a label for.

In NASM, `mov [inputLoopCounter], 0` is a syntax error, because there's no implied operand-size from either operand.  (And in MASM, it would be a `mov byte ptr [inputLoopCounter], 0`.)

---

semi-related: [Confusing brackets in MASM32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129743/confusing-brackets-in-masm32) - `foo ptr [123]` works as an alternative to `ds:123` for indicating a memory operand, not an immediate, where insanely `[123]` would still be an immediate.  Also related: [Assembly difference between [var], and var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39474332/assembly-difference-between-var-and-var/39474660)

---

If MASM allows it in the data section,  `foo:` `db ...` would just declare a label without an implied size, separate from any data declaration.

But apparently MASM does *not* support that in the data section, so you're stuck with variables, unless you want to switch assemblers.  [How to store 4 characters in a define doubleword in assembly language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56281407/how-to-store-4-characters-in-a-define-doubleword-in-assembly-language)