# MASM Offset vs. Label for addressing

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I'm currently working my way through the Irvine x86 Assembly book, and I'm on chapter four.

They've introduced the `OFFSET` directive, but I'm confused on why I'd ever use it. Why wouldn't I just take the label (which is already the address of that data)? It seems like `OFFSET` just adds extra noise.

I have this small program to illustrate my point. I have a label for some data called `array` and I can move the elements of my array into `al`. But the book is talking about using the `OFFSET` directive to get the address of `array` and move it to `esi`. But this just seems unnecessary to me as I could just use the label.

I have two sections of code that do the same thing below. One where I'm using the label to access the elements of the array and the other where I'm using `OFFSET` to move the address into `esi` and then access the elements of the array.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode: DWORD

.data
    array   BYTE 10h, 20h, 30h, 40h, 50h

.code
main PROC
    xor eax, eax        ; set eax to 0

    ; Using Labels
    mov al, array      
    mov al, [array + 1]
    mov al, [array + 2]
    mov al, [array + 3]
    mov al, [array + 4]

    ; Using Offset
    mov esi, OFFSET array
    mov al, [esi]
    mov al, [esi + 1]
    mov al, [esi + 2]
    mov al, [esi + 3]
    mov al, [esi + 4]

    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

Are they really just two ways to achieve the same thing?

Later on in the book when talking about pointers, they have this example:

```
.data
arrayB byte 10h, 20h, 30h, 40h
ptrB dword arrayB
```

And this makes sense to me. `ptrB` holds the address of `arrayB`. But then they say, "Optionally, you can delcare **ptrB** with the `OFFSET` operator to make the relationship clearer:"

```
ptrB dword OFFSET arrayB
```

That doesn't make it clearer to me at all. I already know `arrayB` is an address. It looks like `OFFSET` is just thrown in there and it's not really doing anything. Removing `OFFSET` from that last line would literally achieve the same thing. What exactly does `OFFSET` do if I can just use a label to get the address anyways?

Comment: Your first version doesn't need the `mov al, array`, it's useless. Note that in masm `array` is not an address, it's the value (at least in instructions).

Comment: Irvine's `WriteString` for example needs an address in a register, which you can get with OFFSET. You can also work with LEA, but that's a matter of taste.

Comment: @Jester Are you sure? I've stepped through it with a debugger in Visual Studio and the first element of the array (10h) is moved into ```al```.

Comment: @Jester Wait, I think I see what you're saying. In my ```mov al, array```, I'm moving the value at ```array``` into ```al```, where in my other examples, I'm using indirection.

Comment: @rkhb I see. Would I be unable to move the address into a register without ```OFFSET``` (or at least, not easily)?

Comment: @Jester: it's no more useless than any of the other loads that all get overwritten without being read :P Note the corresponding `mov al, [esi]`.  For consistency with the other loads the OP could have written `mov al, [array + 0]`, or written the other loads as `mov al, array + 1` etc.  (Or better, `movzx eax, byte ptr [esi + 0]` etc.)

Comment: @RobertStefanic: The other method is LEA: `lea esi, array`. This will load the address of the first byte of array into `ESI`. `LEA` has tricky and confusing application possibilities, so stay at `OFFSET` as beginner.

Comment: @rkhb Got it. I appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: @rkhb: More importantly, there's zero benefit to ever using LEA to put a 32-bit constant into a register.  It's a waste of code-size vs. `mov`-immediate, so you should never use it without a register in the addressing mode in 16 or 32-bit code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are they really just two ways to achieve the same thing?

Yes, assembly has *many* ways to do things.

The C equivalent would be
`char *p = array;` then using `p[0]`, `p[1]` etc. vs. using `array[0]`, `array[1]`, etc.

**The advantage of putting a pointer in a register is that it saves some code size when you use it repeatedly; 2-byte `mov` instruction with just opcode + ModRM instead of encoding the absolute address into every instruction separately for a `[disp32]` addressing mode.**

The other advantage is that you can *increment* the pointer with `inc esi`.  In other cases where you don't fully unroll a loop, you need either a pointer or an index in a register.

A plain pointer is usually better than `[array + ecx]`, especially better than `[array + ecx*4]` because indexed addressing modes have some downsides.  (`[array + ecx]` is technically not indexed; it's `[base + disp32]` and doesn't need a SIB byte, and doesn't count as indexed for [Micro fusion and addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes)).

You can use byte offsets, though (e.g. `add ecx, TYPE array`), to allow a `[base + disp32]` addressing mode into a static array of `int` instead of `[disp32 + idx*scale]`.

Using `[disp32]` every time avoids needing an extra instruction to put the address in a register.  `mov reg, imm32` is only a 5-byte single-uop instruction, but it still might not be worth it for performance before a couple static array accesses.  It might depend on the how often your code is already hot in the uop cache vs. how often it has to fetch/decode.  (Saving code size improves L1 I$ hit rate, or at least means more instructions fit in one cache line, so it can be worth it to use more instructions / more uops if it saves code size in something that's not in the hottest inner loop.)

Before a loop (not fully unrolled), you'd normally need an instruction to zero a loop counter / index anyway, like `xor ecx, ecx`.  Using `mov reg, imm32` is only 3 bytes longer, and no extra uops.  If you're saving 4 or 5 bytes every time you use the pointer instead of an indexed addressing mode, you already come out ahead from just one array reference per iteration.  And at a cost of no extra uops.  (Ignoring any minor differences between the outside-the-loop cost of executing an xor-zeroing vs. mov-immediate instruction.)

Note that for x86-64, you'd typically put a static address in a register with a 7-byte RIP-relative LEA.  And for you code to be LargeAddressAware at all, you can't use `[array + rcx]` because that only works with a `[disp32 + reg]` addressing mode, not `[RIP + rel32]`.

---

And BTW, for consistency I'd recommend this over `mov al, array`

```
    mov al, [array + 0]
    mov al, [array + 1]
    ...
```

The first comment under your question is from someone you confused by doing `mov al, array` and then `mov al, [array + 1]` using 2 different syntaxes for similar addresses; I think Jester thought you *intended* something like `mov al, OFFSET array`.  BTW, you could instead write it this way (I think)

```
mov al, array
mov al, array + 1
```

**but I always recommend using square brackets around a memory operand for clarity.**  Especially if you ever look at NASM syntax where that's *always* required, but some people recommend that convention even if you only use MASM.  (But beware that MASM does *ignore* brackets in some cases, when there's no register: [Confusing brackets in MASM32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129743/confusing-brackets-in-masm32) so don't think that using brackets in MASM makes it work like NASM.)

---

BTW, the performance-efficient way to load a single byte is to zero-extend it into the full register, instead of merging into the low byte of a full register.  **`movzx eax, byte ptr [esi]`**

---

**Also BTW, yes, `mov esi, OFFSET array` (5 bytes) is the most efficient way to put a static address in a register (code size and performance).**  `lea esi, array` is 6 bytes (opcode + modrm + `[disp32]` addressing mode) and can run on fewer execution ports; never use LEA without a register in 32-bit mode.

In 64-bit mode you want `lea rsi, array` because MASM automatically uses RIP-relative addressing for that, which you want.  Otherwise still use `mov esi, OFFSET array` (yes ESI, not RSI) for code that isn't LargeAddressAware and can still take advantage of compact code using 32-bit absolute addresses.

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer. I was looking for confirmation that my two examples had the same results, and your comparison to C really made it clear to me that there's more than one way do something. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything about ```OFFSET``` and I take it that I'm not, but you've shown why it's advantageous to put the address in a register and why someone would use it. I've re-read your answer a few times now and there's a lot for me to digest here. Thanks again.