# Difference between two instructions: mov eax, dword ptr fs:[30h] and mov eax, large fs:30h in dereferencing PEB?

Tags: debugging, winapi, assembly, x86

Example A:

```
mov eax, dword ptr fs:[30h]
mov ebx, byte ptr [eax+2]
test ebx, ebx
jz NoDebuggerDetected
```

Example B:

```
mov eax, large fs:30h
mov eax, dword ptr [eax+18h]
cmp dword ptr ds:[eax+10h], 0
jne DebuggerDetected
```

Both according to book (Practical Malware Analysis) are suppose to access fs segment and check value within PEB, but second example:
`mov eax, large fs:30h` is not dereferencing the `fs:30h` so why is this considered valid?

`fs:30h` stores pointer to PEB, so doing `[eax+18h]` would result in  dereferencing `fs + 48h` which wouldn't dereference PEB and would be invalid?

Is my logic somehow wrong or does 'mov eax, large fs:30h' results in implicit dereference?

-Thanks

Comment: I assume this IDA/IDA pro related but `mov eax, large fs:30h` is the same as `mov eax, large fs:[30h]`. The fact the brackets don't appear doesn't mean anything. That is similar to MASM which makes `[]` optional in many cases. I'm just guessing since I don't personally use the debuggers in question.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised this would work `mov ebx, byte ptr [eax+2]` since that is moving a byte to a 32-bit register. I would have expected DWORD PTR.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [Confusing brackets in MASM32](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25129743) (which uses MASM syntax, like this disassembly), although that doesn't mention the `large` keyword;  IDK what that means.  x86 machine code doesn't have any different way of encoding a 32-bit absolute address.  (Although `mov` to EAX has 2 forms: ModRM encoding vs. `moffs32` absolute address without ModRM).  But anyway, I'm sure it's just a 32-bit load into EAX from the address `fs:30h`.  The presence of a segment register and `:` means it's a memory operand, not an immediate or just an Sreg.