# length of a string in assembly (confusion about how program works)

Tags: string, assembly, masm

I have an assembly program which writes the length of a string in ax register but I am a little bit confused about some instructions.

```
include \masm32\include64\masm64rt.inc
.data
string db "mama", 0        ; so here I declared a string "mama". What happens in memory?
.code
 main proc
xor ax, ax                 ; here I initialize ax with 0.
lea rsi, string            ; here, I move in rsi register the adress of string, right? But how the string is stored in memory? Now in rsi I have the adress of the first char "m" of "mama" string?
 @@:                       ; this sign creates an anonymous label
cmp byte ptr [rsi], 0      ; so this says compare 0 with with 1 byte found at the adress pointed to by rsi, right? But I still don't get it. Why 1 byte? rsi is pointing to the first char or to the whole string?
jz @F                      ; jump if zero to the nearest @@ (forward)
inc ax                     ; so now i'm pointing to the first character so ax=1
inc rsi                    ; here what happen? The pointer is incremented to point to the second char from string?
jmp @B                     ; jump to the nearest @@ (backward)
 @@:
invoke ExitProcess, 0 ; invoke ExitProcess API
ret
 main endp
end
```

My confusion is that I'm not sure if I think about how this program works in a right way. Am I thinking this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

`inc ax` increments the 16-bit value by 1 — the processor doesn't know what `ax` is used for but it does know this is a 16-bit addition.

`inc rsi` increments the 64-bit value by 1 — the processor doesn't "know" whether this is an integer or pointer, but it does know this is a 64-bit addition.

This program (though just a `main` and no function) is similar to a `strlen` function:

```
short strlen ( char *p ) {
    short count = 0;
    while ( *p != '\0' ) {
        count++;                // increment 16-bit counter
        p++;                    // increment 64-bit pointer by adding 1 to it
    }
    return count;
}
```

The processor treats pointers like integers.  Integers that when dereferenced refer to memory locations.  Incrementing a pointer by 1 in assembly language makes it point to the next byte of memory — memory locations have integer numbered addresses, so two consecutive memory addresses will differ by the value 1.

Note that due to use of short, 16-bit data type for the length counter, this program will have an overflow error if the string's actual length is >= 32768 (if `short`, which is signed is understood) or >= 65536 (if `unsigned short` were used instead of `short`).

Comment: `unsigned short` is arguably a more accurate reflection of the code: there's no undefined behaviour if it wraps, just a really stupid choice of register width that makes it unusable as an array index without first sign or zero extending it.  And that's inefficient on real CPUs for no reason, e.g. not breaking the dependency on the old value of RAX by only clearing the low 16 bits, and needing operand-size prefixes on xor and inc.  `eax` would be 100% justified if you don't want to support strings > 4GiB, and be more compact than `rax`, but `ax` not at all.

Comment: (Of course this code clearly doesn't care about efficiency.  SSE2 is baseline for x86-64 allowing us to go about 16x faster for data hot in L2 cache, and even for a byte loop this is counting inside the loop instead of pointer-subtract after.  And it has both `jcc` and `jmp` instead of just `jcc` at the bottom.)

Answer (score 1):

```
string db "mama", 0
```

4 bytes `0x6d 0x61 0x6d 0x61` ('mama') are stored somewhere in the data segment of the program's memory. `string` stores the first byte's address in the data segment i.e. 'm'.

```
xor ax, ax

lea rsi, string
```

I believe the operation should be `lea rsi, [string]`.
(EDIT: As [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) mentioned in the comment below, in MASM assembler this syntax is fine)

`string` points to the address of first char. Now `rsi` points to the same address.

```
@@:                       ; this sign creates an anonymous label

cmp byte ptr [rsi], 0
```

rsi points to the beginning of the whole string. The compare operation compares one byte at rsi with zero. If it is zero, it assumes the end of the string and jumps to exit:

```
jz @F                      ; jump if zero to the nearest @@ (forward)
```

If value at rsi isn't zero:

```
inc ax
```

Remember we are storing the length of the string in ax. So for each valid character, we are incrementing `ax` by 1.

```
inc rsi

jmp @B                     ; jump to the nearest @@ (backward)
```

Point `rsi` to the next character ('a') and jump to @@. The code after the first @@ will again check if the next char ('a') is zero, and increment the count (`ax`) by 1, so `ax` will become 2. This will continue until it reaches a 0, where the program assumes end of the string.

```
@@:

invoke ExitProcess, 0 ; invoke ExitProcess API

ret

 main endp

end
```

Exit code.

Sidenote: You can use a program like gdb with breakpoint at the beginning to walk through each step. With `info registers` command you can check their values. Ask google for more advanced commands/methods.

Comment: This is MASM so `lea rsi, [string]` and `lea rsi, string` are identical, both RIP-relative LEA of the symbol address.  [Confusing brackets in MASM32](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25130189)