# Addressing Modes and memory source vs. destination in x86 MASM assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I have looked at many threads regarding this topic and all are confusing. I have not seen a visual for any of the answers that can help me.

I do not understand the difference between all these statements:

```
mov eax, ebx
mov [eax],ebx
mov eax, [ebx]
```

If anyone can create a table with values and show me, that would be great.

Comment: `eax` = the value of  register `eax`. `[eax]` = the contents of memory at the address specified by `eax`.

Comment: @interjay Can you make a table that shows the values please.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. If you've worked with pointers in C then it's like the difference between `p` and `*p`.

Comment: @interjay Yes, Im good with pointers. Can you make it visual using them please?

Answer (score 7):

In Intel's syntax, adding square brackets around register names, labels, or constants (*) will result in the data in memory pointed to by the register/label being used for the operation.

(*) [This answer by Ross Ridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129743/confusing-brackets-in-masm32/25130189#25130189) deals with some of the peculiarities of MASM when using the square brackets.

```
mov rax, rbx
```

**copies** the contents of `rbx` into `rax`.

---

```
mov rax, [rbx]
```

**loads** the qword referenced by `rbx` into `rax`.

---

```
mov [rax], rbx
```

**stores** the contents of `rbx` to the qword in memory pointed to by `rax`.

---

In C-style syntax the expressions above can be written as:

```
rax = rbx
rax = *rbx
*rax = rbx
```

Comment: @Sep Roland So what if I do this, mov eax, 2      |  mov [eax[, 2

Comment: @Csaas33 Assuming that last "[" is a typo, next is what these instructions do: `mov eax, 2` **loads** the value 2 into the `EAX` register (`EAX`changes), and `mov [eax], 2` would **store** the value 2 in the memory location whose address is contained in `EAX` (`EAX` does not change). But MASM would complain because it does not know the *size* of the memory location! You have a choice of `mov byte ptr [eax], 2`, `mov word ptr [eax], 2`, and `mov dword ptr [eax], 2`.