# Copy a register's content to an immediate memory address in assembly

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

In MASM 32 how can I copy the value of a register (for example AL) to an immediate fixed address in the memory (for example address 30h).
So like this

```
MOV [address], register
```

I tried this with MOV

```
MOV [30H], AL
```

and this also

```
MOV DS:[30H], AL
```

but it didn't work, so what to do?

Comment: `MOV [30H], AL` would definitely work in NASM like you tagged originally.  `ds:[30h]` is correct syntax for MASM.  (*[Confusing brackets in MASM32](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25129743)*).  If it doesn't assemble, what's the error message? If it does, what does the resulting machine code disassemble back to, if not a store to `ds:30h`.

Comment: It assemble, but the program crashes due to this line.

Comment: Of course, if you run this instruction in a Windows executable, you'd expect it to fault since that virtual address won't be mapped.  (Except in Win9x maybe.)  This would make sense in a DOS .exe after setting DS, or maybe in a DOS .com (to store into the PSP)

Comment: So, it is completely correct, but the problem is in windows ?

Comment: But by using ds: i don't have any variables declared in the data section, so it is correct also?

Comment: That would be one way to put it.  Most people would say the problem is in your code, trying to store to memory it hasn't mapped.

Comment: Windows executables use a flat memory mode where DS base = 0 so linear address = offset.  `ds:whatever` has nothing to do with the `.data` section of your program.  (All mainstream 32-bit OSes use a flat memory model, and 64-bit mode enforces that in hardware.)

Comment: Besides the two duplicates linked at the top of the page, [Does Linux not use segmentation but only paging?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/469529) is applicable re: x86 segmentation being unrelated to ".data segment" or "section" (Windows and Linux are similar enough in this respect.)

Comment: @PeterCordes question please, so is there any solution to make the executable program run on Windows without crashes?

Comment: Only write to memory you've allocated, e.g. in `.data`/`.bss`, or the stack, or with `malloc` or `VirtualAlloc`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Understood. Can you please explain more on what you said "since that virtual address won't be mapped"?